# Showing table data in secondary table when column value is selected

Tags: powerbi

I have a table which shows the number of emails sent and received in two separate columns. This is separated into months on the rows:

[image]

I have another table where I want to display the messages that were sent/received and the colleagues name:

[image]

I want the user to be able to click on a number in either the emails sent column or the emails received column and the message that is then shown in the secondary table is either the emails sent or the emails received (depending on which column is selected) for the month selected. How would I go about doing this?

The behavior I have at the moment is that when either columns are selected, both the emails sent and emails received are shown in the secondary table for the selected month row.

Answer (score 1):

I think the fastest solution would be to create two separate table visuals under the first table in your question: one - for emails sent, the second - for emails received.

And in one table you should filter out "Emails Received" and in the second "Emails Sent". For this purpose, you can just use the "Filters" pane.

[PowerBI Filters panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1a2Y8.png)

Or you can just add the "Sent" and "Received" flag to your table with messages.